# Flatlist React Native - No Data Display

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming

We are developing a react native application using Flatlist. Binding data from API service & its working fine. Suppose no data available in service we need to display separate design for that.

We are using "renderEmptyListComponent" for that

sharing the code, please check

```
<FlatList style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
              data={this.state.dataSource}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (this.renderMovie(item))}
              keyExtractor={item => item.salesID}
              renderEmptyListComponent= {this.noItemDisplay}
              ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}>
            </FlatList>
```

please guide me how can we do this?

Comment: There is no such prop "renderEmptyListComponent". As per docs, it is 
"ListEmptyComponent". http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.47/docs/flatlist.html#flatlist

Answer (score 16, accepted):

might want to use this instead:

```
<FlatList 
  style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
  data={this.state.dataSource}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (this.renderMovie(item))}
  keyExtractor={item => item.salesID}
  ListEmptyComponent={this.noItemDisplay}
  ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}>
</FlatList>
```

Or if that also doesn't work do the old ternary jsx-eroo

`{ this.data ? <FLatList /> : null }`

Hope this helps