# Picture does not render in Flatlist, but appears in when the modal is opened

Tags: image, react-native, rendering, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to render a bunch of pictures in a flatlist.  Currently, the pictures do NOT appear when the page is rendered.  However, when I click on the screent where the picture should be, it correctly opens a modal, which allows me to view the picture.  Why would the picture NOT appear in the flatlist, but in the modal?

First, I get the data I need from the backend

```
componentWillMount() {
    apiService.getAlarmList().then((res) => {
        console.log('NotificationHistory:componentWillMount:getAlarmList:res:', res);
        for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            const thisHistory = res[i];
            thisHistory.image = null;
            thisHistory.idx = i;
            this.getItemImage(thisHistory.path, thisHistory.idx);
        }
        this.setState({ cameraHistory: res });
    });
}
```

this.state.cameraHistory now has an array with all the necessary data.

```
renderCameraHistory() {
    return (<FlatList
        data={this.state.cameraHistory}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {                        
            // console.log('NotificationHistory:renderCameraHistory:item:', item, index);
            // console.log('this is rendering the flat list', item.image);
            if (item.image !== null) {
                return (
                    this.renderSingleHistory(item, index)
                );
            }
        }}
        //Because we're using the indexes(which are ints) we need to convert them to strings first
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        // keyExtractor={(item) => item.path}
        //this needs unique keys, however the current array has multiple copies of the same item
        //item.key is supposed to work, but still 
        //extraData={this.state.toggleRefresh}
    />);
}
```

contains the flatlist component.

Each picture is then rendered via the function below.  When the picture is clicked on, a modal is opened and a bigger version of the picture appears, along with a button to close the modal and go back to the list of pictures.

```
renderSingleHistory(item) {
    const dateNTime = item['date-time'];
    const dateArr = dateNTime.split(' ');
    const dateOnly = dateArr[0];
    const timeOnly = dateArr[1];
    const logoPic = Config.images.homeIcon;
    const picForFlatList = item.image;

    return ( 
    <View style={styles.cardView}>
        <View style={styles.pictureView}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                    this.getBigPicture(item);
                }}
            >
                <View
                    style={{
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                    }}
                >
                    <Image
                        source={{ uri: picForFlatList }}
                        style={{
                            resizeMode: 'contain'
                        }}
                    />
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.textView}>
            <View style={styles.topTextView}>
                <Text>{item.serial}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.bottomTextView}>
                <View style={styles.bottomLeftTextView}>
                    <Text>{dateOnly}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.bottomRightTextView}>
                    <Text>{timeOnly}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>

    </View>
    );
}
```

Additional note:  if I use a static image as the source, a flatlist of the static image is rendered, HOWEVER, when I click on the image, the picture that's located inside the array, gets loaded into the modal(the picture I want loaded in the flatlist).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use ListEmptyComponent inside FlatList.  Due to the state not being updated instantly, when the renderItem method is called, the initial object does NOT contain the item.image(2 calls are made to the back, so it takes some time).  Therefore, ListEmptyComponent acts as a placeholder until state is completely updated and allows something to be rendered instead of trying to render null.

I was able to discover this via this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611180/flatlist-react-native-no-data-display)